# How to insert multiple translations during the creation of a new Entity

Tags: php, translation, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 with the [behavioral-extensions](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions) (in particular Tree, Sluggable and Translatable)

In the examples a new translation is made by first storing an article, finding it and then making a translation.

```
// first load the article
$article = $em->find('Entity\Article', 1 /*article id*/);
$article->setTitle('my title in de');
$article->setContent('my content in de');
$article->setTranslatableLocale('de_de'); // change locale
$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

Is it possible to create an article together with it's translation?

I've tried

```
//assuming the translationListener has default locale en_us
$article = new Article;
$article->setTitle('my title in en_us');
$article->setContent('my content in en_us');
$em->persist($article);

$article->setTranslatableLocale('de_de')
$article->setTitle('my title in german');
$article->setContent('my content in german');

$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

But this results in German content in both the article-table and the translation-table.

How can I insert multiple translations during the creation of a new entity?

Comment: EDIT: My bad. didn't read the docs. (I'm not sure I understand. Why is there an expectation that updating and persisting the same object twice would write separate data to two different tables?)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but maybe you should flush your entityManager before the first call to `persist` too, so the listener receives two different objects (well, in fact the same object updated at two different places)